# How to run a curl (Using curl command in java) command from java?

Tags: java, curl, libcurl

I was able to get 200 once I hit the curl code in a terminal so I assume how I write testStytch is ok so far. But once I tried to integrate into a java file, I get a bad request response. I am kind a no clue right now.
https://github.com/libetl/curl this is what I referred to convert my curl code.

This is the error I got.
HttpResponseProxy{HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request [Date: Thu, 22 Apr 2021 23:21:42 GMT, Content-Type: application/json, Content-Length: 189, Connection: keep-alive, Traceparent: 00-d3a39218eb8d091ffe3bf5cb474692ce-353a1a23da4e5dc4-01] ResponseEntityProxy{[Content-Type: application/json,Content-Length: 189,Chunked: false]}}

```html
 @RequestMapping(value = "/loginByStytch" , method = RequestMethod.POST)
      public synchronized String loginByStytch(ModelMap model, HttpServletRequest
      request) throws Exception {

      mapper = new ObjectMapper();
      String hashPassword;
      
      UserInfoBean userInfoBean = mapper.readValue(request.getParameter("data"),
      new TypeReference<UserInfoBean>() { });
      
      String testStytch = "-k -X POST 'https://test.stytch.com/v1/magic_links/send_by_email' -u project-test-b3ca64c2-b0c8d73:secret-test-s5lO3O -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{​​​​​​​\"email\":\"yiikikkano@nllllc.com\",\"magic_link_url\":\"http://localhost:8080/ROOT/NC/authenticateByStytch\",\"expiration_minutes\":500}​​​​​​​​'";

      HttpResponse response = curl(testStytch);
      
      InputStream inputStream = response.getEntity().getContent();
      String jsonContent = convert(inputStream, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));

      request.getSession().setAttribute(Constant.SESSION_NAME, null);
      
      return "redirect:/timeline";
      
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you can use curl with a process object, the handmade way, I don't know much about this lib you used, but isn't much known, so I would avoid, you can get a inputStream too using this, and used to fill the response stream:

```
String command = "curl -X POST https://your_url/path --data foo=bar"; 
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
process.getInputStream();
```